# Adding a simple HTML Landing Page before a Wordpress Website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have been given a web application developed in Wordpress by another developer and I am not an expert in Wordpress as a framework.

Our webapp is hosted in SiteGround. What I am trying to do is add a simple HTML Template Landing Page with CSS and JS before the actual Wordpress site is loaded. I thought I could do this by adding a new index.php file on the root folder in SiteGround.

The reason I want to do this is because I want the landing page to have a different theme than the rest of the app. We are launching the website too soon for me to do it my preferred way (Django), so I just need this quick fix (even if it's a bit hacky) for the release date, so that then I can re-do the application in a better way.

Any ideas? I want to add something like this that then redirects to the Wordpress site: https://html5up.net/landed

Comment: Do you want a preloader (a layer on top of the loading page) or a completely different page that forwards to the actual home page?

Comment: Why don't you select "static page" in the WP customizer dialog and then style this page as you want?

Comment: Johannes, I don't do that because it inherits from the theme used for the rest of the site.

Comment: Nathaniel, I don't want a preloader. I want a completely different page.

Comment: @JohannesFilter your example shows a preloader, so you should pick a different, more correct, example for your question.

Answer (score 2):

Create landing page template & for making it different from the rest of the site you should create different header,footer files so that default won't be added in landing page.
header-landing.php
footer-landing.php 
Include both the header & footer files inside custom landing page template.

```
<?php
/*Template Name: Landing Page */
get_header('landing'); ?>
Put here html content of the landing page.
<?php get_footer('landing'); ?>
```

Customize your header file,only add those files that is required on landing page header.Please see the beloe code for adding different header styling in the same theme. save it as header-landing.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) & !(IE 8)]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
      <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
      <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/example.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
      <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site landing">
      <div id="main" class="site-main site-landing">
```

you can hide or remove extra css on the landing page header using its class "landing" and "site-landing".

For example
.landing h1

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I am understanding this better now. However, when I put a template inside the theme of the website, even if I put the HTML code inside the template, it still pulls the overarching theme of the other template (even though I created footer-landing.php and header-landing.php (and left them empty). For instance:

`<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Landing Page
 */
get_header('landing'); ?>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<?php get_footer('landing'); ?>`

This will render the page with the header INSIDE the content space for the other template. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please see above edited code, you can only pull js,css that is defined in header-landing.php and can also hide/remove using default theme extra css using landing page class.